# Storing data in custom keyboard

Tags: objective-c, save, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am building a custom keyboard that learns the way you type for smarter auto-correct. In order to learn...
 I need to be able to STORE data to the users device. I've tried using `NSFileManager` with `NSDocumentsDirectory` but nothing is getting saved int he AppExtension. (I tested the code (copy paste) in a regular app (non-app-extension) and it worked). I even enabled "Requests Open Access" in the .plist and re-installed the keyboard... still wouldn't save data.

Is there a way to store data in an app-extension?

---

Possible solutions I've pondered:

•Maybe creating a contact in the users address book that has my info in it (if app-extensions are allowed to do that), but a user might be suspicious as to why my app is requesting permission to modify their contact's address book).

•Displaying a hidden UIWebView that uses javascript injection to store and read data [Safari Javascript Database](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH3-SW1), but I'm afraid this data might be erased if cache is ever cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: now this is no longer working for me on iDevice beta 5 (with requestOpenAccess enabled OR disabled)? But it still works on SIMULATOR beta 5? Hmmm

__ original post below: *_*

It turns out NSUserDefaults DOES save data, it just does not work on BETA 3 simulator, but did work on BETA 5 iDevice. RequestsOpenAccess does NOT need to be enabled!

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"com.company.keyboard.uniqueCodeHere"];//uniqueCodeHere can be anything... we just have to make sure the SuiteName isn't equal to your info.plist bundle ID so we add a random uniqueCode to the end of this ID.
[defaults setObject:@"myStringData" forKey:@"savedStrings"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

*Note, SuiteName Can NOT equal bundle ID in info.plist or it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: Not getting this solution how coule this working i faces same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162773/communicate-with-custom-keyboard-extension-with-host-app-not-working-in-device-b