# Communicate with Custom Keyboard extension with Host App not working in device but works in simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working with custom keyboard extension. that almost done but i just facing issue with device when i communicate data with extension and my host app that not woking in device but same thing this working in simulator. My code is following:

**HostApp View controller:**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

    _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myapp.myappname.targetKeyboard"];
    [_defaultvalue setBool:YES forKey:@"Layout"];
    [_defaultvalue synchronize];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)RightAction:(id)sender {


    _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myapp.myappname.targetKeyboard"];
    [_defaultvalue setBool:YES forKey:@"Layout"];
    [_defaultvalue synchronize];

}

- (IBAction)leftAction:(id)sender {

    _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myapp.myappname.targetKeyboard"];
    [_defaultvalue setBool:NO forKey:@"Layout"];
    [_defaultvalue synchronize];
}
```

And i check this `BOOL` value in my extension target using following code and change keyBoard layout according to my need:

```
-(void)LoadKeyboardview
{

_defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.myapp.myappname.targetKeyboard"];

        if([_defaultvalue boolForKey:@"Layout"])
        {
            self.ObjKeyLayout=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"keyboardLayout" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
            [self addGesturToKeyBoard];
            self.inputView =self.ObjKeyLayout;

        }
        else{

            self.ObjKeyLayout=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"leftLayout" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
            [self addGesturToKeyBoard];

            self.inputView =self.ObjKeyLayout;

        }

}
```

That same code working well in simulator ios8 device iPhone5. please is there any more code needed for this i read in apple doc that said `NSUserDefaults` initWithSuiteName help me in this thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I have already set **RequestsOpenAccess** in plist and at setting->keyboard-customkeyboar->Full Access ON

My extention Plist:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution that i create new provisional profile and enable **app-groups** and setting `app group` from my `Xcode` project from `target-->capability--Expand App Group` and by tap on **+** add app group like following screenshot:

[image]

And doing same thing for my keyboard extension target. Then i used this setting app groups identifier in `NSuserDefault`:

```
 _defaultvalue = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.keyboaredExtention"];
     [_defaultvalue setBool:NO forKey:@"Layout"];
    [_defaultvalue synchronize];
```

now that working fine in my device and simulator. hope that helps to others.

Comment: @quocViet i added my answer how did i solve this please follow think

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8, a custom keyboard and the containing app can communicate using a shared container.

This is achieved by asking the user to allow full access, which is a setting in the iOS settings app under General->Keyboard->your keyboard->Full Access (ON/OFF).

You should add this setting to your keyboard's Info.plist:

```
RequestsOpenAccess
```

For further info, read Apple's iOS8 Custom Keyboards API Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW11

Comment: thanks for answer i do the same thing i said in my question that working well in my simulator but only device that not working.